# My Php blade variable is not working in simple php

Tags: php

My Php blade variable is

```
{{$user->account_expiry_date}}
```

My simple php crud code

```
Dt = date("d-m-Y");
```

I store value of blade variable value in simple PHP variable.

```
$ac_expiry='{{$user->account_expiry_date}}';
```

Now I echo `$ac_expiry` and same echo working

But when I use in some condition same variable arn't working

```
If ($dt <=  $ac_expiry) {
    Do something not working
}
```

Comment: If  should be @If

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use using laravel format you have to write like this

```
@if(true)
  echo "Success";
@endif
```

Or if you want to use in core php you can write like this

```
<?php 
if(true){
  echo "success";
}
?>
```

Comment: i know dear but i want to use both core php and laravel also i want use this variable {{$user->account_expiry_date}} in below sql  query  $sql = "SELECT database where = ";

Answer (score 1):

If statement should be like

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
 I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
 I have multiple records!
@else
 I don't have any records!
@endif
```

here is the doc [laravel docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#custom-if-statements)

In your case, statement should be

```
@if ($dt <= $ac_expiry) { Do something not working }
```

Comment: i know dear but i want to use both core php and laravel also i want use this variable {{$user->account_expiry_date}} in below sql query $sql = "SELECT database where = ";